# How to upload bulk data in supperssion table in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have to enter approx 100,000 email id to auto suppression table but I am not able to find the way to upload the bulk data.  There is the option to upload the data via activity to Suppression List but We have created the suppression list separately and this option is not coming when trying to update it via activity.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Upload the file to your FTP and use the Import activity in Automation Studio.